# Mouse effect for banners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing an exercise. This is my interface. Now I want a mouse effect for two banners on the left:

[image: before]

When we move mouse on **each banner**, **that banner** will be replaced by a text box with same size, green background (without affecting the other banner) as following.

[image: after]

I know we can do this effect somehow with javascript, but since i am learning html, javascript is not easy for me, could you guys please help me as an example? This is my code:

```css
#parent {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0px;
}

.right {
    border-left: 2px solid;
    border-color: rgb(215,217,216);
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: right;
    width: 270px;
}
.left {
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin:0px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}

header20 {
    font-size: 16pt;
}

#inner { 
    margin-left: 10px;
    width:730px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
    display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="row">
    <div class="right">
        <br>
        <img src="http://dbclipart.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Red-banner-clipart-image-1.png" style='width:250px;height:50px'>
        <br><br>
        <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/banner-20clipart-normal_1283818525.jpg" style='width:250px;height:50px'>
        <br><br>
        <table style='width:250px;background-color:rgb(211,238,208)'>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <header20><span style='color:rgb(17,56,96)'><b>This is the first table</b></span></header20>
            <ul style='padding-left:25px;margin-top:0px;magrin-bottom:0px'>
                <li>First point</li>
                <li>Second point</li>
                <li>Third point</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table style='width:250px;background-color:rgb(211,238,208)'>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <header20><span style='color:rgb(17,56,96)'><b>This is the second table</b></span></header20>
            <ul style='padding-left:25px;margin-top:0px;magrin-bottom:0px'>
                <li>First point</li>
                <li>Second point</li>
                <li>Third point</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
        <div id="inner">
            <br>
            <img src="smallpic.png" style='float:left;margin:0.1cm;width:85px;height:85px'>
            <p style='margin-left:2cm;font-size:22.0pt;margin-top:6pt;color:rgb(0,56,96)'><b>This is the title of the page -  bla bla bla <br>Timetable for the next month</b></p> 
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The first line of the content</p>
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The second line of the content</p>
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The third line of the content</p>
            <br>
        </div>   
   
        <table align='center'>
        <tr>
            <td style='padding-right:25px'><img src="pic1.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
            <td style ='padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px'><img src="pic2.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
            <td style ='padding-left:25px'><img src="pic3.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a JSBin for you which shows how to solve this. The solution **only** requires CSS and no JavaScript! You can see it here:

https://jsbin.com/hecesusiwu/1/edit?html,css,output

Here are the steps to solve:

- Wrap image in a `div`
- Add another div with text in it
- Hide the inner div
- Show the innter div on hover

Comment: thanks a lot James, I thought about putting the two banners in a new `div`. But when we do it, the distance between 2 banners (as well as distance between the below banner with the first table) will be expanded (which is not allowed in this case). The distance between banners with borders (top, left, right) must be remained.

Comment: In my example I think that the banners are the same distance apart as in your example. Are they not?

Comment: No, since you use `div`, the form is broken. the distance between banners is expanded. The distance between banners with right border is expanded also. Could you please check it again?

Comment: @gnase I've updated the link in my example - the banners are now correctly position vertically and left-right :)

Comment: thanks. But the distance between the below banner with the first table is still larger than the distance between two tables. That is what i mean to say when you use `div` :D

Comment: and the distance between two banners is also larger than distance between two tables. :D

Comment: I've updated the answer with a new link - the banners and tables are now all equally spaced. You are really making me earn this answer-accept! :P

Comment: thank you, accepted alredy. Could you tell me how you did to avoid the problem with expanded space between banners when you use `div` ? And I still do not understand why the banners and the below tables appear on the left of the page although i put them in `<div class="right">`?

Comment: The `div` element doesn't have any extra spacing unless you add it. The `margin` and `padding` defaults to 0.

Comment: hei James, could you help me to align the text "Hello world, this is a test message for this effect" in the center of the block. I mean the distances between the text line with above and below margin are same? I tried to add one more class for this but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an exercise I'm just going to give you a little tip:
Wrap the Banner and a hidden Text box. When hovering the **wrapper** you simply hide the Banner and show the Textbox.

If you're too lazy to try it out, here a simple solution:

```css
.switcher {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}
.switcher > img {
  display: block;
}
.switcher:hover > img {
  display: none;
}
.switcher > .switch-text {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(211, 238, 208);
}
.switcher:hover > .switch-text {
  display: block;
}
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}
.right {
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(215, 217, 216);
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 270px;
}
.left {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Calibri;
}
header20 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}
#inner {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 730px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  /* equal height of the children */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="row">
  <div class="right">
    <br>
    <div class="switcher">
      <div class="switch-text">
        Some Text here
      </div>
      <img src="http://dbclipart.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Red-banner-clipart-image-1.png" style='width:250px;height:50px'>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="switcher">
      <div class="switch-text">
        Some Text here
      </div>
      <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/banner-20clipart-normal_1283818525.jpg" style='width:250px;height:50px'>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <table style='width:250px;background-color:rgb(211,238,208)'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <header20><span style='color:rgb(17,56,96)'><b>This is a table</b></span>
          </header20>
          <ul style='padding-left:25px;margin-top:0px;magrin-bottom:0px'>
            <li>First point</li>
            <li>Second point</li>
            <li>Third point</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table style='width:250px;background-color:rgb(211,238,208)'>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <header20><span style='color:rgb(17,56,96)'><b>This is another table</b></span>
          </header20>
          <ul style='padding-left:25px;margin-top:0px;magrin-bottom:0px'>
            <li>First point</li>
            <li>Second point</li>
            <li>Third point</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Alex. I have one more question. Do you see that the banners and the below tables are put in `<div class="right">`. I do not know why here it appears on the left hand side of the page?

Comment: `.row { display: flex; }` Is causing that ;)

Comment: wow, you are such a Profi. Thanks a lot! Sorry I accepted answer of James already. But I used another account to vote for you also. :)

Comment: Sure no problem! I'm doing this stuff since 2 years now. Helping others on SO helps me learning and practising as well x)

Comment: Hei Alex, could you please help me again. How can I move the text inside 1 div, sothat I can align this text and move it inside banner as I want? Thanks

Comment: @gnase Simply add another _inner_ - wrapper, or work with padding

Comment: thank you very much, Alex. I used padding and it worked. Earlier i used `vertical-align:middle` but it did not work. :)